# Does normalization affect on system identification result?

Tags: matlab, normalization, system-identification

suppose a nonlinear system with 3 input-3 output,in-out data has been logged on a experiment at the same time,if we do/do not a normalization(take data between -1 and 1), on in-out data ,is result the same,after a black-box(Nonlinear arx identification or Nonlinear Grey-Box or arx and  Identification,and so on) identification?

Comment: This question seems like it needs a lot more context to be answerable. What sort of system? What sort of normalization? What sort of "in-out data"? What do you mean by "black-box identification"?

Answer (score 0):

i tried that,take data between -1 and 1,then do a "nlarx" identification,the result was not the same.